# $n>2$, let $d$ be the largest integer such that $d|n!$ and $d^2<n!$,is it true that $d$ is even?

Tags: number-theory, approximation

$n>2$, let $d$ be the largest integer such that $d|n!$ and $d^2<n!$,is it true that $d$ is even?

I checked this for $3\leq n\leq 35$,the highest power of $2$ that divides $d$ is
$1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6, 6, 1, 2, 5, 10, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 7, 5, 8, 2, 13, 13,
6, 4, 8, 2, 5, 2, 4, 9, 13, 21.$

Let $$a(p)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lfloor \frac{n}{p^i}\rfloor$$
then 
$$n!=\prod_{p\leq n}p^{a(p)}.$$
If $$d=\prod_{p\leq n}p^{b(p)}<\sqrt{n!}$$
then
$$\log d=\sum_{p\leq n}{b(p)\log p}<\log \sqrt{n!}.$$

This is like how to choose a pile of stones whose total weight is closest to the capacity of a bag, will the smallest stone be chosen?

In terms of probability, the probability of $b(p)=0$ is  $\frac{1}{1+a(p)}$, then the probability of $b(2)>0$ for all $n>2$ is about
$$\prod_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{a(2)}{1+a(2)}\approx \prod_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{n}{1+n} =0,$$
so mayby there are any counterexamples?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the distribution of powers of $2$ could be between the two numbers close to $\sqrt{n!}$ and so how you get your probabilities.  The smaller ones involving odd numbers are $2!=1 \times 2$ and $3!=2 \times 3$ and $13!=78848 \times 78975$ though only the first of these is the way round you are considering

Comment: @Henry If $n=13$ then $d=78848$ as $78975^2>13!$.Let $n!=d*t$, it seems that both $d$ and $t$ are even if $n>13$.

Comment: Interesting, from some point on it will be difficult to find $d$ and $t$ by brute force because the number of divisors gets extremely large.